# Panning not working within my camera script

Tags: c#, input, camera, unity-game-engine

I've got a camera script that I'm working on and I just cannot get the camera pan to work at all. It's recognising the input, but it's not moving the camera at all.

It was working at one point but it reset the camera upon zooming or rotating, now the zooming and rotating work perfectly. This issue was due to the function `PositionRotation` which you can find at the bottom.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;
[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse drag Orbit with zoom")]
public class DragMouseOrbit : MonoBehaviour

{
public Transform target;
public float distance = 5.0f;
public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
public float ySpeed = 120.0f;
public float yMinLimit = -20f;
public float yMaxLimit = 80f;
public float distanceMin = .5f;
public float distanceMax = 15f;
public float smoothTime = 2f;
public float zoomFactor = 5f;
public float panFactor = 10f;

private Transform m_Transform;
float rotationYAxis = 0.0f;
float rotationXAxis = 0.0f;
float velocityX = 0.0f;
float velocityY = 0.0f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    rotationYAxis = angles.y;
    rotationXAxis = angles.x;
    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
    }
}
void Update()
{
if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            CameraRotate();
        }
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            CameraPan();
        }

    if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") <= 0)
        {
            CameraZoom();
        }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") >= 0)
    {
        CameraZoom();
    }
    }
}


public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < -360F)
        angle += 360F;
    if (angle > 360F)
        angle -= 360F;
    return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}

public void CameraRotate()
{
    if (target)


            {
                velocityX += xSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * distance * 0.02f;
                velocityY += ySpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 0.02f;
            }
            rotationYAxis += velocityX;
            rotationXAxis -= velocityY;
            rotationXAxis = ClampAngle(rotationXAxis, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
            PositionRotation();
}


public void CameraPan()
{
    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())   
        {
        Debug.Log("right click has been pressed dumbfuck");            
            //transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * panFactor);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * panFactor);
        }        
}


public void CameraZoom()
{
    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
        //transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * +Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoomFactor);

        PositionRotation();

        distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoomFactor, distanceMin, distanceMax);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, transform.position, out hit))
        {
            distance -= hit.distance;
        }

    }
}

void PositionRotation()
{
    Quaternion fromRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationXAxis, rotationYAxis, 0);
    Quaternion rotation = toRotation;

    Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
    Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

    transform.rotation = rotation;
    transform.position = position;
    velocityX = Mathf.Lerp(velocityX, 0, Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
    velocityY = Mathf.Lerp(velocityY, 0, Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your Update function. It calls CameraZoom all the time because you set

```
Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") <= 0
```

And CameraZoom calls PositionRotation, where you reset the positon of the camera to the original position.

Try setting it to

```
if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") <= -0.1)
{
    CameraZoom();
}
if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") >= 0.1)
{
    CameraZoom();
}
```

That should do the trick.

Cheers
Tobi